# Is it possible to use a fluid mesh as a domain for another simulation?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation

I thought it might be a cool effect to have a smoke simulation inside of a fluid simulation. If the liquid shifts or separates the smoke behaves accordingly as its domain has changed, maybe swirling around or shifting densities. Maybe even using a fluid as a fluid domain.

It would probably be a nightmare to bake if it is indeed possible.

Comment: Domain uses object's *Bounding Box* to define its shape, so this won't work I suppose

Comment: @SergeL Do you think there would be a way of containing fluid or smoke if the fluid sim has a collision mesh and is invisible, giving the illusion of this effect?

Comment: Fluid as collision shell for smoke sim might work, and I recommend you not to bake everything at once. Firstly export fluid as alembic cache then play with smoke